# "Скоростные" Real-Time соединения

Tags: tcp-ip, сокет

**Добрый день!**

Возник вопрос, каким образом лучше и удобнее следует устанавливать "скоростное" соединение в режиме реального времени. Как можно обмениваться с сервером данными на предельной скорости? К примеру, каким образом работает Skype или тот же TeamViewer, которые обмениваются данными с сервером->клиентом на другой стороне практически моментально? Какие есть техники? Было бы очень приятно послушать описание методов (например, через сокетное соединение).

**Спасибо!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скайп обменивается "практически моментально"? Да, если для Вас несколько минут - это моментально.

> например, через сокетное соединение

А собственно по другому - сложно. Можно конечно и голубями, и извозчиком.

Вы уже пробовали данные передавать? Тестировали скорость? Или просто так, утром проснулись и решили оптимизировать то, что даже не написали?

Для размышлений. Если хорошо постараться, то можно использовать udp, при правильном подходе даст хорошие результаты.